# В чем ошибка? Почему неожиданный, когда ожидаемый?

Tags: javascript

Почему `unexpected token '('` во второй функции?

```js
function() {
  if ($(this).attr('data-code') == "CA") {
    function() {
      $('.message').html($(this));
      $('.message').fadeIn(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: а чего за функция просто посреди кода, без имени, без присваивания куда-либо?

Comment: если этот ваш код выполнить, то так и пишет _"function statement requires a name"_, а вот упомянутая вами ошибка не в этой части кода

Comment: [ВОТ](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics), почитайте как обьявлять функции

Comment: @teran, сообщение зависит от браузера. Хром выдает вполне себе _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (_

Comment: @Grundy интересно :) фф более информативен :)

Answer (score 0):

У первой функции должно быть имя, а вторая там вообще не нужна

```
function funcName() {
  if ($(this).attr('data-code') == "CA") {
      $('.message').html($(this));
      $('.message').fadeIn(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: зачем функции обязательно имя?